# Minio: put object with additional data

Tags: c#, .net, minio

Does anyone know if it is possible to put object with additional data in Minio for .net? I thought that metadata parameter of the PutObject method could be used for this purpose, but apparently it's just a http request headers list. And it doesn't work like I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need to use the headers (metadata parameter for PutObjectMethod) with the "X-Amz-Meta-Metadata" prefix.